# How to create a custom URL to another domain in Wordpress

Tags: rewrite-rules

I wonder it's possible to use Wordpress for my purpose. I need a website where I can register a user and then create a custom URL for them. For example. The user 1 has http://domain.com/user1 and so one. Of course the http://domain.com/user1 redirect to another domain, for example http://domain.uk. Is this is possible with native hook in wordpress called rules ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `author_rewrite_rules` filter to change rules to look like ones you want them to look, and then implement redirection on `request` or `template_redirect` filters/actions.

P.S.

URL you want to implement isn't really good as it already fits to the page rewrite rules.